# Chart js: hide some labels in the legend

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts

Is it any way to hide some labels from the legend in `chart js`?

I know, that I can hide all legend, using this option:

`legend: {
    display: false
}`

but I need to hide just a part of labels in the legend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an answer. It is possible to generate new labels, using `generateLabels` function such like this:

```
legend: {
    labels: {
        generateLabels: function(chart) {
            return [
                { 
                    text: 'text',
                    fillStyle: 'red'
                }
            ]
        }    
    }
}
```